# Content area defined in 9 patch image doesn't work for custom view

Tags: android

Currently, I have a custom view `BarChart`. I wish to have some red shadowing effect on it. I'm using nine patch image technique to achieve so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minHeight="240dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background_red"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <org.yccheok.jstock.gui.charting.BarChart
        android:id="@+id/bar_chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my custom view, there is line of code, where I will draw string at the end-y of the view.

```
// Drawing string at end-y of BarChart custom view.
canvas.drawText("2007", x0, getHeight(), textPaint); 
canvas.drawText("2008", x1, getHeight(), textPaint);
```

I avoid my custom view from **"touching"** any of the red shadow, I define my content area of 9-patch, so that it doesn't touch the red shadow.

As you can see, the **content area** are pretty much stay away from red shadow.

[image]

I thought my drawn text will never touch the red shadow area, as I restrict my content area (entire custom view?) stay away from red shadow area. However, it doesn't work.

[image]

Am I having wrong expectation on the content area of 9 patch image? I thought Linear Layout's "content" is my custom view `BarChart`. Hence, `BarChart` shouldn't be touching the red shadow as specific in 9 patch image. (http://www.shubhayu.com/android/9-patch-image-designers-vs-developers)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove android:padding="0dp" from LinearLayout. It overrides padding from 9-patch.

Comment: Does the official document says it somewhere?